# $scope being cached on page in only one method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, angular-template, angular-templatecache

When this page loads the `$scope` in each of the methods below contains the same `id` value. The `self.gridData` is populated as it should be and accessible in the `selectAllClicked` method.

When I navigate away from/back to the page all `$scope` ids a regenerated as they should be except for the one in the `.selectAllClicked` method. In the `.selectClickedAll` method the `id` of the `console.log($scope)` is from the original page load. Since `self.gridData` is loaded in the new `$scope` but the old `$scope` is called in `.selectAllClicked`, the `angular.forEach` never fires.

```
    var self = this;

    $scope.selectAllClicked = function(){
        console.log($scope);
        angular.forEach(self.gridData, function(item) {
            item.selected = self.selectAllCheckbox;
        });
    };

    var dataSuccess = function(data){
        console.log($scope);
        self.gridData = data.data;
        angular.forEach($scope.gridData, function (cr) {
            cr.rowId = rowIdCount++;
        });

        self.tableParams.total(data.rowsCount);
        return self.gridData;
    };

    var setupGrid = function(){
        console.log($scope);
        self.tableParams = $rootScope.gridParamsHash["recordingsList"] || new NgTableParams({count: 25 }, {
            counts: [25, 50, 100],
            getData: function(params) {
                var filter = params.filter();
                var sorting = params.sorting();
                var count = params.count();
                var page = params.page();
                return recordingsService.getGridRecordings(page, count, filter, sorting, $scope.externalFilterParams.callType, $scope.externalFilterParams.externalDateFilters ).then(dataSuccess, dataFail);
            }
        }, 3600000); // This delay is a workaround to prevent the ngTable from reloading
    };

    function init() {
        console.log($scope);
        setupGrid();
    }
```

This appears (I believe) to be an issue related to [ng-table's](http://ng-table.com/#/) `header` directive in the first `td` element below. It's loading the checkbox from the `headerCheckbox.html` and storing in the templatecache. Again assuming here, but it seems like this forces the checkbox to be tied to the original scope, not the re-rendered scope.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="headerCheckbox.html">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selectAllCheckbox" ng-change="selectAllClicked()" />
</script>


<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table testTable" fixed-table-headers="scrollable-area">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data" ng-class="{'selected':row.rowId == rowId}" ng-click="setClickedRow(row.rowId)">
        <td width="40" header="'headerCheckbox.html'"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.selected"/></td>
        <td data-title="'Username'" filter="{ username: 'text'}" width="30">{{row.username}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas how to force the `$scope.selectAllClicked` to apply itself to the newly rendered `$scope`?

Comment: Dumb question, but shouldn't it be `ng-change="vm.selectedAllClicked()"` in the template and `self.selectAllClicked` in the controller? I haven't seen both $scope binding and controllerAs binding used in the same template like this before... usually it's one or the other. Then again, I haven't seen a lot of things.

Comment: Try using the angular.element and $compile function to add the template (headerCheckbox.html) to the first td.  If you're still stuck, create a jsfiddle or plunker so we can help.

Comment: @Will Sorry, should have mentioned that the directive belongs to the ng-table plugin (updated my post).

Comment: @LarryTurtis thanks for the suggestion... no luck however.

Comment: @NealR I'm not familiar with ng-table.  Your best bet is to create a plunker/jsfiddle so everyone can chime in.